# Convert OData ApplyQuery method result with $expand option to List<T>

Tags: json, entity-framework, list, odata, iqueryable

I have an OData get method:

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
   [MyEnableQuery(PageSize = 48, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy | AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.Skip | AllowedQueryOptions.InlineCount | AllowedQueryOptions.Filter | AllowedQueryOptions.Expand | AllowedQueryOptions.Select, AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.SubstringOf | AllowedFunctions.ToLower)]
    public IQueryable<tbDefine_Products> GetProducts(ODataQueryOptions opts,[FromODataUri] int CategoryID)
    {
        ProductHandler _handler = new ProductHandler();
        IQueryable<tbDefine_Products> _list =_handler.GetProductActiveList(CategoryID);
        return _list;
    }
}
```

And i have overrided ApplyQuery method to query:

```
 public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        IQueryable<Object> _list = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions).Cast<Object>();
        return _list;
    }
```

I am using a form of ODate Query with expand Option:

```
http://localhost:5125/api2/product?CategoryID=-1&$skip=9&$top=1&$expand=tbDefine_Category
```

I want in my ApplyQuery method  to convert base.ApplyQuery result to some form of list and then iterate through it for some modification but i dont know how...

```
 /*    IQueryable<MyExpandedType> _list = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions).Cast<MyExpandedType>();
              List<MyExpandedType> _list2 = _list.ToList<MyExpandedType>();
               for (int i = 0; i < _list2.Count; i++)
               {
                      some modification here
               }  */
```

i get the following error

> Unable to cast object of type 'SelectAllAndExpand`1[EDMX.tbDefine_Products]' to type 'EDMX.tbDefine_Products'.

Answer (score 0):

one thing I believe is that you need to correct the signature of your applyquery method. As it returns a Iqueryable the signature should be the same I guess.

public override IQueryable ApplyQuery.